# If we add or remove a module inside modules.conf, do we need to reinstall everything?

Tags: voip, freeswitch

In freeswitch, if I add or remove a module inside modules.conf, do I have to go through

```
configure -C
make
make install
```

over all again?

Answer (score 3):

The modules.conf.xml that you would edit is located in $PREFIX/conf/autoload_configs/, The ones referenced by user1278519 is based on the different samples we include in our tree.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: for the modules.conf.xml, i have 5 of them inside the conf folder `./conf/sbc/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml ./conf/vanilla/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml ./conf/rayo/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml ./conf/curl/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml ./conf/insideout/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml.` Do you know which one is it that I modify. I use master branch, so this is the latest code-base

Answer (score 2):

The list in `modules.conf` sets what is built when you do a `make` each time.

If you want to add a module, you should enable it in `modules.conf` for next time, but you can then just build and install that one, e.g.:
`make mod_event_zmq-install`

Remember to enable the module in `conf/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml` for the next FreeSWITCH restart and also load it with `load mod_YYYY` if you want it now.

Comment: for the `modules.conf.xml`, i have 5 of them inside the conf folder `./conf/sbc/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml
./conf/vanilla/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml
./conf/rayo/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml
./conf/curl/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml
./conf/insideout/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml`. Do you know which one is it that I modify. I use master branch, so this is the latest code-base

Comment: You need to choose one of them, e.g. vaniall, to use as your base configuration. Those are 5 full sets of configurations, and you have to choose.